# Inverter MOSFET Snubber: RC or Schottky diode?

Tags: mosfet, inverter, snubber

I've researched this question and found a lot of theory, but not much practical anecdotal experience. I would like to hear from those with physical knowledge of this.

I've constructed a transformer based pure sine inverter. I haven't implemented a snubber network yet, hoping the FET body diodes might suffice. I don't have a lot of confidence in that since blowing up FETs in spectacular fashion. I'm not sure I need to include a schematic as it seems a pretty straightforward question for someone with experience in the field.

The question being:

In an N-channel FET H-bridge, what advantage (or disadvantage) does a drain-source RC snubber have over Schottky diodes in the same position?

Comment: They do very different things so it’s impossible to give an answer to cover all cases. Do you have a specific problem you are trying to resolve?

Comment: Also, your base design should function without snubbers (unless flyback or thyristor based) without MOSFETs blowing up before you should start thinking about adding snubbers.

Comment: I don't have enough power electronics knowledge to say whether I have a problem or not, but I have been looking at other people's inverter power boards and some use RC snubber networks and others use diodes. I have the components on hand to add the RC  to my inverter, but I hate to do things over, and want to make sure what I do is the best route.

Comment: My top tip would be too add placeholders for both external Schottky and RC and only populate if deemed necessary during development.

Comment: OK, I have that option. Let me ask then what kinds of use case has one preferred over the other? I have another post on this project called Bulletproof H-Bridge that gives an overview of the project and failures so far, by the way.

Comment: Body diode too slow, causing over/undershoot -> parallel Schottky helps. Some high frequency ringing needs to be damped out -> RC.